# Issue with sed command in Bash for string replacement

Tags: sed

I've been looking for a way to find-and-replace strings in all fortran files in my current directory. Most answers on here are along the lines of using:

```
sed -i 's/INCLUDE \'atm/params.inc\'/USE params/g' *.f
```

or

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/INCLUDE \'atm/params.inc\'/USE params/g' *.f
```

However, when I use either of these the bash line continuation > pops up on the next line as if it's expecting input or another argument. I haven't seen anyone else encounter this and I am not sure what to do with it. Are my commands incorrect; am I missing something?

Comment: BashFAQ #21, at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021, gives the canonical mechanism for doing this.

Comment: BTW, `sed -i` is a non-standard extension -- the POSIX standard for `sed` doesn't guarantee that it'll be available, and even when it *is* available it may behave in different ways (the MacOS X version won't work with your given command). If you want to write portable code, consider using `ex` instead, or another mechanism given as standards-compliant in the above-mentioned FAQ.

Comment: Can you confirm that you can reproduce the bug with **the exact commands given here**? Specifically, `'s/old-string/new-string/g'`, with `old-string` and `new-string` as the literal, exact source and destination text (not some other text for which you're using those strings as placeholders)?

Comment: BTW, large parts of this are not really bash-related -- `sed` is not part of the shell, but provided by the operating system (meaning we don't know how `sed -i` is supposed to behave unless we know the OS you're running, and knowing that your shell is bash vs ash or whatever has no bearing on that behavior once `sed` is invoked). However, I'm theorizing that the *actual* source and destination strings you're using parse in a manner you don't expect by the shell, with the effect that `sed` isn't actually being started -- but we can't diagnose that without those actual strings.

Comment: ...and, yeah, there's your problem. `\'` isn't how you substitute a single-quote in a single-quoted string.

Comment: I switched the strings to the actual strings I'm using. The end goal is to switch include files to modules. Oh, okay thank you. I thought it would act as an escape, I saw an example doing that somewhere online. What is the correct way?

Comment: If you're using `'`s in your pattern and replacement (and string interpolation is not going to be an issue), just double quote the whole expression and you won't need to escape anything.

Comment: @SeanBright, that works, but I wouldn't call it best-practice -- one needs to be more careful in double quotes; using single-quotes for data intended to be literal is the better habit to be in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, fair enough, but I would risk it over having to mentally parse your answer (not a shot at you, but a shot at the inherent complexity)

Comment: @SeanBright, I understand that, but the nice thing about my answer is that it's a purely mechanical operation -- if you're generating text to be interpreted by a shell, "put single-quotes on the outside and replace any inner single-quotes with `'"'"'`" is a very simple rule to follow, whereas safely escaping double-quoted content is much more dangerous.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, maybe we need a `sed` replacement for our `sed` replacement?

Comment: @SeanBright, ...this is actually one of the few situations (perhaps the only situation?) where I'm a fan of `perl` -- being able to do search/replace oneliners that refer to environment variables for literal content to be used on either side, so nothing needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with the original:

- You weren't protecting your `/` in the literal data from being parsed by `sed` rather than treated as data. One very readable and explicit way to do this is with `[/]`.
- You were trying to use `\'` to put a literal `'` in a single-quoted string. That doesn't work. The common idiom is `'"'"'`, which, character-by-character, does the following:

  1. `'` - exits the original single-quoted context
  2. `"` - opens a double-quoted context
  3. `'` - adds a literal single-quote (protected by the surrounding double quotes)
  4. `"` - ends that double-quoted context
  5. `'` - resumes the outer single-quoted context.

Thus, consider:

```
# note: this works with GNU sed, not MacOS sed or others
sed -i 's/INCLUDE '"'"'atm[/]params.inc'"'"'/USE params/g' *.f
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistype of the question which I just edited. I have not been typing the actual commands this way. I am not sure what other code you'd like to see since I am not doing anything other than this one command.

Comment: @WhS4, do you get the given behavior with **the exact strings** `old-string` and `new-string`? If not, you'll need to build a better example.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I suppose I should have read up on my syntax a bit more before diving in, but thank you none the less.

Comment: just a side note: I found another solution to the literal / problem. sed can use any character as a delimiter, so when dealing with strings containing /, some people use @ (although anything not in the strings would work) for the delimiter. I tested and this works